# Calabash iOS - How to clear text in a webview

Tags: cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios

clear_text doesn't work for me when testing a webview. Does anyone know of a different method for webview/cordova apps? The locator I'm using is "webView css:'input#username'" but that seems to be fine as enter_text is working.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Lewis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks but `set_text("webView css:'input#username'", "")` didn't work. I ended up using the solution you mentioned [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/151)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
set_text("webView css:'input#username'", "")
```

You might also try using the [WebView JavaScript API](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/06-WebView-Support#javascript-api)

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem, I ended up using something like this :

```
Then /^I clear a field with "([^\"]*)" text$/ do |name|
   name = set_value name
   element = query("UITextFieldLabel text: '#{name}'")[0]
   touch(element)
   wait_for_keyboard
   name.to_s.split('').each do |c|
      keyboard_enter_char 'Delete'
   end
end
```

Details are in here: [Clear field with calabash-ios](https://thescimus.com/2017/07/25/clear-field-with-calabash-ios/)